# Perf not working properly in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, perf

I installed perf but when I try to use it shows this message

> Kernel address maps (/proc/{kallsyms,modules}) were restricted. 
>   Check /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict before running 'perf record'.
>
> As no suitable kallsyms nor vmlinux was found, kernel samples 
>   can't be resolved.
>
> Samples in kernel modules can't be resolved as well.

Also tried the GTK but it is showing this message

> GTK browser requested but could not find libperf-gtk.so

What should I do?

Comment: check /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict

Comment: The content of kptr_restrict is 1. Is that normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set `kptr_restrict` to `0`:

```
sudo sh -c " echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict"
```

Note that the GTK error has nothing to do with this but indicate that you ar missing a library.

Comment: Hi, same problem here, and I've tried to set this value to 0 already (under KVM)